# Gnuplot: Change x-axes format from 1e+001 to 1e+1

Tags: format, gnuplot

I want to change the x-axes format from 1e+001 to 1e+1. How can I do this? Currently I'm using

```
set format x '%.1g'
```

in order to achieve the x-axes labels to be 1e+001 etc. How can I delete those two zeros? I'm very new to gnuplot. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following format to remove the useless zeros (ie change 1e+001 to 1e+1, etc).

```
set format x '%.1t+e%T
```

Check `help format specifiers` for further information about the formats in Gnuplot.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for :)